# passing objects into function through void pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, parameters, casting, void-pointers

I am writing a simple Memory Manager. I am trying to simplify this function so others can 
just add the object they want to allocate as the first parameter. The Memory Manager will 
allocate the space for that object, and set the object's pointer to point to the allocated 
space. Problem is I'm not sure how to go about making the parameter so just about any type 
of object can be passed in, without having to cast it like crazy to get it to work.

**Here is the function:**

```
bool MemoryManager::Allocate(void** data, unsigned int allocSize, bool isArray)
{
    if((m_Heap.m_Pool == nullptr) || (*data != NULL))
        return false;

    if(isArray)
        allocSize += sizeof(unsigned int) * 4;

    void* mem = m_Heap.Allocate(allocSize);
    if(mem)
    {
        *data = mem;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

**This is currently how I have to call it to get it to work:**

```
int* Test = NULL;
MemoryManager::GetInstance()->Allocate((void**)(&Test), sizeof(int), false);
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Use a template and take it by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using templates and overloading, you can operate directly on the type of `data`, including its size:

```
template<typename T>
bool MemoryManager::Allocate(T*& data)
{
    size_t allocSize = sizeof(T);
    ...
}
```

When it comes to arrays though, normally we try to steer clear of pointers in C++. Use `vector<T>` for example. You can specify your own allocator.

I would consider whether you even want to return a raw pointer in fact; you might consider returning a smart pointer object.

Your array size calculation is flawed; I am not really sure what you're trying to do there. I would expect that `allocSize` is really element size, and thus the calculation is:

```
allocSize = (allocSize * elementCount);
```

But you don't have any way to know how many elements the user is requesting.